# how to achieve google maps terrain look INURL

Tags: google-maps, terrain

i am using this url:

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Zagreb,+Croatia&aq=&sll=45.808351,15.897484&sspn=0.010066,0.016544&vpsrc=0&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Zagreb,+Croatia&t=m&z=14&ll=45.794222,16.048298&output=embed

what do i need to add and where to get the TERRAIN look not the one shown by defaut?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change one parameter.

Instead of

```
t=m
```

use

```
t=p
```

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Zagreb,+Croatia&aq=&sll=45.808351,15.897484&sspn=0.010066,0.016544&vpsrc=0&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Zagreb,+Croatia&t=p&z=14&ll=45.794222,16.048298&output=embed

Answer (score 0):

I came across this looking for the **Google Fusion Tables** answer.
In that case, the parameter needs to be:

```
t=4
```

Found it on Google Groups
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/Bj_u6QPohaA
Thanks, Kathryn